# A small pandigital equation

Tags: calculation-puzzle

```
 _ _ _ _ _ × 8 = _ _ _ _ _
```

There is a number that you can put in the left-hand side of the above equation so that the blanks are filled in using every digit from 0 to 9 exactly once. What is that number?

Comment: If there are multiple solutions, you are usually expected to state that.

Comment: I didn't actually know there were multiple solutions myself. I was a bit hasty posting this puzzle, it seems.

Comment: how to find the number of solutions of such a pandigital puzzle?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is more than one correct answer.

> (10459, 83672), (10469, 83752), (10537, 84296), (10579, 84632), (10592, 84736), (10674, 85392), (10679, 85432), (10742, 85936), (10794, 86352), (10932, 87456), (10942, 87536), (10953, 87624), (10954, 87632), (12073, 96584), (12307, 98456), (12345, 98760)

Comment: Huh, I had just gotten to your third answer right before this showed up.

Comment: +1. Thanks, I tried to find a proof for the JonTheMon's solution and failed to do so. What an ugly tricky puzzle...

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case.

Answer (score 6):

> Oddly enough, the numbers are 12345 & 98760. I knew that the first two digits of the top had to be low numbers, 1 and 2, so I just tried it out, and it worked!
>
>  This worked out well since the 1's digit of the multiplication (before carrying) ends up being 86420 (8 stepping down by 2), and we have carry values of 12340
>  So, we get:
>  8 - 0 + 1 = 9
>  8 - 2 + 2 = 8
>  8 - 4 + 3 = 7
>  8 - 6 + 4 = 6
>  8 - 8 + 0 = 0

Comment: Yep, that's correct!

Comment: 0 is lower than 2... the complexity of this puzzle is to find the proof, not to find the answer..

Answer (score 4):

A list of all the possible solutions to this:

```
(03187, 25496)
(04589, 36712)
(04591, 36728)
(04689, 37512)
(04691, 37528)
(04769, 38152)
(05237, 41896)
(05371, 42968)
(05789, 46312)
(05791, 46328)
(05839, 46712)
(05892, 47136)
(05916, 47328)
(05921, 47368)
(06479, 51832)
(06741, 53928)
(06789, 54312)
(06791, 54328)
(06839, 54712)
(07123, 56984)
(07312, 58496)
(07364, 58912)
(07416, 59328)
(07421, 59368)
(07894, 63152)
(07941, 63528)
(08174, 65392)
(08179, 65432)
(08394, 67152)
(08419, 67352)
(08439, 67512)
(08932, 71456)
(08942, 71536)
(08953, 71624)
(08954, 71632)
(09156, 73248)
(09158, 73264)
(09182, 73456)
(09316, 74528)
(09321, 74568)
(09352, 74816)
(09416, 75328)
(09421, 75368)
(09523, 76184)
(09531, 76248)
(09541, 76328)
(10459, 83672)
(10469, 83752)
(10537, 84296)
(10579, 84632)
(10592, 84736)
(10674, 85392)
(10679, 85432)
(10742, 85936)
(10794, 86352)
(10932, 87456)
(10942, 87536)
(10953, 87624)
(10954, 87632)
(12073, 96584)
(12307, 98456)
(12345, 98760)
```

Don't forget you can use 0 at the start of the first number :)

Comment: usuallly in puzzles of this type leading zero is disallowed.